# MVC 3 2 models in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC (i.e. the last few days) and i would like to know if what i have done is the best way.

I have a view that is a combination of an insert item form with a list details form underneath for a particular entity.  As such i kind of need 2 models for the page in order to avoid doing things like `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().EventTypeID, "Event Type")`.

What i have done is set the model to be `Tuple<IEnumerable<Event>,Event>` that way i have both the single item and the collection of items. Can anyone suggest a less hacky alternative or is this the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 solutions.

- You should create a different View Model Class (a simple class with both models as properties)
- You can assign it to the ViewBag.Model1 ... ViewBag.Model2 ... But this is dynamic so you will have no intellisense and you can get errors at runtime.

You should use a ViewModel like this

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public TypeOfYourModel MyModel1 { get; set; }
    public TypeOfYourModel MyModel2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would this sit in the Models folder as currently it is empty because my model classes are EF 4.1 pocos in a seperate library ?

Comment: You can create a new ViewModel folder if you like, or a different assembly. Depends on you application layer(s).

Comment: OK thanks, this solution is not a million miles away from using the Tuple but feels a bit less hacky somehow.

Comment: Yes, the Models folder is specifically for these ViewModel classes. Your actual domain model would typically be in a different assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a ViewModel that would contain both objects you want to pass.

```
public class NewEventViewModel
{
    public Event NewEvent { get; set; }
    public Event EventDetails { get; set; }
}
```

You could also use `ViewBag`, but it is not strongly typed so you would not get IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Model object just for the view, with 2 properties, one for the single entity and one for the collection, and then you can pass this composed object as the model for the view